# Change bios password with python

Tags: python, bios

Im going to have to make changes to a lot of bios of lenovo thinkpads, related with device guard and administrator password. There are two device guards, one in Windows and other in the bios, I only want to enable/disable the one in the bios.

Comment: Nope.  Only the BIOS can change the BIOS password.  You will have to go physically to each system, reboot it, and enter the BIOS to make these changes.  The BIOS password is something that you should not change lightly.

Comment: Thats a shame. But do you know how to enable or disable device guard?

Comment: It is usually configured through Group Policy.  Most Group Policy things can be tweaked through PowerShell, but I think you'll have to do some creating Googling.  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/windows-10-device-guard-and-credential-guard-demystified/ba-p/376419

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help